# C# MySQL transaction does not work with code that throws Exception

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using MySQL as my database, and I want to use transaction to make sure everything is intact in case of any arror. But `Rollback()` and `Commit()` does not work as expected.

I was using Dapper at first, I tought the problem was Dapper and I stopped using it, but the result is the same.

The record that I'm trying to insert, is inserted EVEN IF code throws an exception.

```
            var mysql = new MySqlConnection($"server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=PASSWORD;database=DBNAME;port=3306;default command timeout=0;");

            await mysql.OpenAsync();

            using (var tx = mysql.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
            using (var command = mysql.CreateCommand())
            {
                try
                {

                    command.Transaction = tx;
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2) " +
                                          "VALUES ('value1', 0)";

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    throw new Exception(); // <--- THROWING EXCEPTION .

                    tx.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tx.Rollback();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

The **MyISAM** does not support transactions.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I am using InnoDB